# My FutureBuilder's snapshot doesn't have any data after async method in Flutter

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, future

I write a list:  `List<ListClass> listItems;`,I want to push some data to it and show this list on the page

Using this async method:

```
    return Future.delayed(delayTime).then((_) async {
      CollectionTable().getIndexList().then((value) {
        listItems=value;
        print("length="+listItems.length.toString());
      });
    });
  }
```

The getIndexList() method is also an async method,like this:

```
  Future<List<ListClass>> getIndexList() async {
    listItems.clear();
    await listCollection.get().then((value){
      var v = value.data;
      for (var data in v) {
        listItems.add(ListClass(...);}
    });
    return listItems;
  }
```

And th futureBuilder:

```
 return FutureBuilder<Object>(
      future: initHomeList(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        print(snapshot);
        if(snapshot.hasData){
          EasyLoading.dismiss();
          return Scaffold(
            //showing data
          );
        }
        else{
          //loading
          EasyLoading.show(status: 'loading...');
          return Container();
        }
      },
    );
```

But when I debug,the process goes through `snapshot` twice,the first showed `AsyncSnapshot<Object>(ConnectionState.waiting, null, null)`
The second showed`AsyncSnapshot<Object>(ConnectionState.done, null, null)`,but `snapshot.hasdata` is false.
(During the above two print,it hadn't go through the `getIndexList` method,the list was null.

The  I continued,the list got data correctly,but the program jumped to a place I don't know(I use step over),the program is still working?I think.

Could anyone help me fix my code?I want to show page after get data,thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are not returning the result from the future anywhere.
Can you try to change your code like this - this includes the return statement that will pass the data to your snapshot.

```
return Future.delayed(delayTime).then((_) async {
      CollectionTable().getIndexList().then((value) {
        listItems=value;
        print("length="+listItems.length.toString());
        // add this
        return value;
      });
    });
```

If you want to remove 'print' from the code, just use this.

```
return Future.delayed(delayTime).then((_) async {
      return CollectionTable().getIndexList();
    });
```